# Can I build a pair of networks with a DNS server on a different network to the gateway?

Tags: networking, router, debian, dns

## Network Diagram

[ISP] <-> [gateway] <-> (lan 1) <-> [Debian 10 desktop] <-> (lan 2) <-> [DNS Box]

- Lan 1: 192.168.0.X/24
- Lan 2: 192.168.1.X/24
- DNS Box has static IP 192.168.1.8/24
- It is connected via a crossover ethernet cable to my Debian 10 desktop, using its native eth port/interface and a USB eth interface on the Debian 10 box
- The Debian 10 box is then connected to the lan 1 network using its native eth interface/port
- Lan 1 contains a bunch of switches, all which connect to my ISP provided router, which is the gateway to the WAN

## Typical Setup, reason why this one is different/weird

Typically my DNS box is on the same network as Lan 1. Usually I just plug it into the switch, then tell my Debian 10 machine to look for the DNS info at the ip 192.168.1.8. Usually I am on a network where all the devices are connected via switches, and are all on network 192.168.1.X.

However I temporarily moved elsewhere where the local lan is on 192.168.0.X, so I can't plug the DNS box into a switch.

Hence I set up a new static network to connect it to the Debian 10 box, using a spare USB adapter. I can ssh into it.

However it is not working as a DNS server. This is probably because:

- although DNS requests **may** currently being sent to it (I don't know if they are or not as I don't know how to test this)
- I don't think the DNS box knows how to access DNS servers on the WAN / wider internet, because it probably does not have a route to the wider internet
- In order to get this it probably needs me to set up my Debian 10 box as a router, to route traffic from the network 192.168.1.X/24 to 192.168.0.X/24

However please note the first bullet in that list, I am not sure if my hunch is correct here. It might be the case that what I am trying to do is impossible.

## My current config / what I tried

- Debian 10 box has 2 wired network interfaces, they are connected as follows

  - **Interface A: "Eth DHCP"**
  - "Automatic (DHCP) Addresses Only"
  - 192.168.0.22/24
  - DNS Servers: 192.168.1.8
  - **Interface B: "Eth DNS Box Static"**
  - "Manual"
  - 192.168.1.1/24
  - Gateway: left blank (?)
  - DNS Servers: blank/none

## Next steps

At present I am not currently sure what diagnostics steps I should take.

## Solution

- Change to root user and run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Setup iptables as follows:

- `sudo iptables -L` (currently blank)
- `sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface enp3s0f2 -j MASQUERADE`
- `sudo iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enx0050b668976b0j ACCEPT`

This command failed because the network interface name `enx0050b668976b0j` is too long

- Tried changing this with a udev rule - that didn't appear to work
- Info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396382/how-can-i-show-the-old-eth0-names-and-also-rename-network-interfaces-in-debian-9#396383
- Changed using `iproute2`, this may be temporary, not sure at the present time
- `sudo ip link set enx0050b668976b down`
- `sudo ip link set enx0050b668976b name eth1`
- `sudo ip link set eth1 up`

Then ran

- `sudo iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT`

Info for iptables from https://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables

Testing

- ssh'd into my DNS server, pinged `192.168.1.1` (next hop / debian box), `192.168.0.1` (next next hop / ISP router), `8.8.8.8` and `google.com`, all working ok
- Changed some settings on debian network config, including interface names, due to renaming interface to `eth1`, other than this all settings were fine
- Went to a few websites on the debian machine, all working ok

Output from `sudo iptables -L`

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 3):

There are probably a few things you need to do and this still may not work.

Going from RIGHT.

**DNS Box:**

- It needs to list your Debian 10 as a router. You probably need to list 192.168.1.1 as a default gateway there.

**Debian 10 Desktop:**

- It needs a default gateway to be your ISP modem / router. This should be happening automatically as you claim to use DHCP there.
- You have to enable IP forwarding by writing 1 to /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward.
- You may need to properly configure firewall on that system.

**ISP router / modem:**

- You have to add the route to 192.168.1.0/24 network there and to list the IP address of the Debian 10 Desktop as the gateway. This may or may not be supported on that device and using DHCP for the Debian 10 Desktop is suboptimal here.

If the above is not a workable setup (i.e. because of router / modem limitations) your likely only options left are:

- Use NAT on Debian 10 Desktop. It has limitations on its own.
- Merge the two networks into one. Isn't it possible for your ISP router / modem to reconfigure for use of 192.168.1.0/24 network?

Comment: Thanks for this, changed some stuff in my `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file on the DNS box. Looks like the default route is ok now. How do I write a 1 to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`? Surely this is not a permanent change? Tried opening it with vim but that didn't work. Not sure how I should interact with this file.

Comment: Not sure about Debian but `sysctl.conf` an `sysctl` man page should help for persistent setting. Use `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` for immediate and non-persistent change.

Comment: Strange, tried that and just got an error `bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied`.

Comment: with `sudo` by the way

Comment: Just a guess~ **Chmod 777  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward** (change it back to normal when you are finished)

Comment: Do it as root. And `sudo` would only apply to `echo` but not to redirection which is done in current shell as current user. And I am also not sure chmod would work on any file in /proc.

Comment: Ok that seems to be working - do you have any advice regarding how to get started with NAT on my debian system? Even if it's just some potential software I can use for this. I couldn't find any guides online, it's a tricky thing to search for since most of the info is regarding nat problems on routers. You were right, my ISP router doesn't seem to have the required options.

Comment: Hey, it works, I will add a bit more info to my question